# Capistrano - var/www/[app-name]/repo failed build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, server, capistrano

I'm trying to run my initial `cap production deploy` script, but it keeps failing. I have repeated this multiple time. The first time fails with:

```
Directory does not exist 'var/www/[app-name]/repo'
```

Then I run the same command again and I get:

```
fatal: destination path 'var/www/[app-name]/repo' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

I dug into it and it appears that my structure has become: `var/www/[app-name]/var/www/[app-name]/repo`

In my deploy.rb

```
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_to, '/app/[app-name]'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I also just started using `Cap`.. still not reliable for me.. any time it is failing ;/

Answer (score 0):

Adding [Capistrano::SafeDeployTo](https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-safe-deploy-to) do you cap file should resolve this.

#### Gemfile

```
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'capistrano-safe-deploy-to', '~> 1.1.1'
```

#### Capfile

```
require 'capistrano/safe_deploy_to'
```